# Table 'project.migrations' doesn't exist in engine" mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using xampp with laravel, my sql was working fine until suddenly when I wanted to start mysql I got the error

> Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

to solve that I copied the **backup** folder inside the **data** folder in mysql. but now all the tables I had in my project don't exist in the database anymore so I wanted to migrate them again from laravel but I'm getting the error

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view notfound: 1932
> Table 'prostudent.migrations' doesn't exist in engine"

how can I migrate all the tables again? and supposing migration worked is it the right way to launch my laravel project again without errors?

Comment: Did you try logging into your mysql via command client? Have you checked your databases do they really exist or not?

Comment: database was there, i just made new database and migrate everything again to it and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. You just delete old migration and all tables from database 
2. Created a new database with a same name that is initialize in .env file
3. After step 2 just run again php artisan migrate
```